# Time countdown doesn't stop at 0:0.0 and it never reaches the else statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I have problem with reaching the else statement in `Update` method and I don't know how to make this clock stop. `S` The `startTime` is in seconds. If you make it `90.0f` you will have 1.30 minute. The problem is I need to stop this clock when reaches the `0:0.0`.

```
public Text TimerText;
private float startTime = 3.0f;
private bool start = false;
private float _time;
private float _minutes, _seconds;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    start = false;
    startTime = 3.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
   // if (start)
  //  return;
    if (startTime > 0.0f)
    {
        _time = startTime - Time.time; // ammount of time since the time has started
        _minutes = (int)_time / 60;
        _seconds = _time % 60;
        TimerText.text = _minutes + ":" + _seconds.ToString("f1");
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("we are here"); 
}

private void CheckGameOver()
{
    Debug.Log("gameover");
}

public void StartTime()
{
    TimerText.color = Color.black;
    start = true;
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you ever change `startTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.time` and change:

```
if (_time> 0.0f) 
{...}
```

Add `_time = startTime` into `Start()`

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `Time.deltaTime` like Pawel did in his answer.

I know that this problem is already solved but just in-case you want to know why your code is not working, that's because when you did  `if (startTime > 0.0f)`, you are supposed to be decrementing `startTime` in the if statement. If you don't, `startTime>0` will always be `true` which means that the if statement will run forever.

You can still fix this by simply replacing your `if (startTime > 0.0f)` with `if (Time.time < startTime)`. You don't need to decrement anymore but it will work.